# Hardware wallet support?

Tags: wallet, hardware

Will there be any hardware wallet support for EOS tokens after launch date?  Not the ERC-20 tokens, the main (and other) EOS chain tokens.

Answer (score 10):

See bytemaster's answer:

> EOSIO supports the R1 elliptic curve which means every iMac Pro, MacBook Pro, iPhone and iPad can use the secure enclave as biometric secured hardware wallet. The same R1 curve is used on many smart-cards and Android devices.

UPDATE: [Ledger Nano S now supports EOS](https://support.ledgerwallet.com/hc/en-us/articles/360008913653-EOS-EOS-)

I will update this post as more information becomes available.

Answer (score 5):

EOSIO supports the R1 elliptic curve which means every iMac Pro, MacBook Pro, iPhone and iPad can use the secure enclave as biometric secured hardware wallet.

The same R1 curve is used on many smart-cards and Android devices.

Answer (score 2):

You can now build your own with this project we just released: https://medium.com/@liquideos/how-to-build-an-eos-hardware-wallet-a-step-by-step-guide-a62445786c0f

Answer (score 0):

Someone on the EOS Community Forum, claimed that the [CoolWallet S now supports EOS](https://eosforum.org/t/announcement-hardware-wallet-coolwallet-s-supports-eos/856?u=anton).

However, so far I can find no evidence of this [on their website](https://coolwallet.io/). I have made a query and will update this answer if I find further evidence. The website says ERC20 tokens will be supported from quarter 2 2018, so it is possible they are just talking about EOS ERC20 tokens, which isn't so useful at this point.

## Edit

The official website now confirms ERC20 token support. They have also announced on the [EOS Community Forum](https://eosforum.org/t/announcement-hardware-wallet-coolwallet-s-supports-eos/856/4?u=anton) that they plan to support native EOS post-launch. Exactly when post-launch they do not say.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/eos/comments/8i2xfq/announcement_hardware_wallet_coolwallet_s_now/dyolf43/    According to this, they only support ERC20.

Comment: Well there you go. Seems bizarre they are boasting of ERC20 support for EOS less than a month before they are obsolete. But I guess that is marketing departments for you.